# MultiSite Setup

Tags: multisite, wordpress.com-hosting

I'm fairly new to WordPress and am trying to set up a multi site config on my localhost. I followed the instruction here: https://www.nexcess.net/help/how-to-configure-a-wordpress-multisite-network/

[image]

When I go to any of the sub sites (both on frontend and backend) I'm getting a 404 error.

Help please :)

I'm using Apache on a Ubuntu machine.
**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

**wp-config.php**

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Comment: Do you know if the 404s are generated by WordPress or by the server? (Are they themed?) Does wp-admin work on all sites? Is there any chance this is a VirtualHost configuration issue? Anything in the WordPress debug logs - if enabled - or server error logs?